# javascript undefined not null, not empty issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is the statement:

```
  if(attachmentId!=null && attachmentId.length>0&& attachmentId !='undefined'){
   //do something
   }
```

equivalent to:

```
 if (attchmentId) {
     //do something
  }
```

thanks for the help

Comment: `attachmentId !='undefined'` is not the same as `attachmentId !=undefined`

Comment: Once we know what's the real question we can choose another question to close this one as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing :

```
if (attchmentId)
```

is the equivalent of:

```
if(
   attchmentId != undefined &&//NO QUOTE
   attchmentId != '' &&
   attchmentId != null &&
   attchmentId != false &&
   attchmentId != 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

They're not equivalent but the third test `attachmentId !='undefined'` was probably an error (did you want `attachmentId !=undefined` ?).

Another example of difference is that `0` doesn't pass the first test but pass the second one.

You **must** decide what's important to you before you try to write the test. If you **know** you start with a string and you want to test if it's defined and not empty, then you may use the second test.

Answer (score 0):

It can be reduced to this:

```
if (attachmentId && attachmentId.length > 0) {
   //do something
}
```

This will do for arrays and more complex objects that happen to have a `length` property. If attachmentId is supposed to be a string the code above will work the same, but the second part will basically be a noop, so you can just go with:

```
if (attachmentId) {
   //do something
}
```

I am assuming the comparison against `'undefined'` was a mistake - do that and you're not checking if something is actually `undefined`. You're checking it it is different from a literal string that says *"undefined"*.

Also you check the variable first due to the [short circuit rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). It it's either `null` or not defined you don't care about the rest. Otherwise, if you tried evaluating the length before checking if it's `undefined` or `null` you could throw an error there.